# How do perform a task upon a .war file's deployment?

Tags: java, ant, war

I'd like to perform some deployment steps when a war is deployed. By deployed, I mean when it is unpacked by the servlet container (i.e. Tomcat). I cannot find any documentation for this specifically.

This may not be the ideal way to do first time configuration on a war webapp, but I'd like to explore this option if its a possibility.

Also, I'd prefer to specify my tasks using Ant tasks.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Which kind of tasks do you need to perform? Perhaps related to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant

Comment: There are some database entries that need to be populated. The database belongs to something else, but the web app extends that functionality and needs to add some entries.

Comment: See the sql task in ANT, but I think you should really use ANT to build and a dedicated and separate tool to do deployment.